# ios UITableview multiple select options on single cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

Has anyone found a really good way to handle this case in UI?  We have a tableview with a list of items (long list).  Each item is a row and it can be either "selected" or it can be drilled into to see it's children.  What we have in our design (which looks confusing to users because they are used to selecting entire cell and not specific buttons on it) is 2 buttons on the cell (checkmark button and arrow button).  Has anyone found a better way of solving this from design perspective?

Thank you very much. (Current design attached below)
[image]

Comment: There's a reason Google, Apple, and the like have two separate UI flows for multi-selection and single (detail-opening) selection. I'd suggest the same in this case.

Comment: In my case parent is white and its children is light-gray and text color also changes, parent arrow is down which tell the user that there are more items to be loaded and children arrow is forward

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it belongs to https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

*I believe this question belongs to the [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site so I'm flagging it*

That being said, have a look at [Detail Disclosure Buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/buttons/). From the HIG:

> When a Detail Disclosure button is present in a table row, tapping the button shows additional information. Tapping elsewhere selects the row or results in app-defined behavior.